# Using Named Captures with regex match in Ruby's case...when?

Tags: ruby, regex, switch-statement, capture

I want to parse user input using named captures for readability.

When they type a command I want to capture some params and pass them. I'm using RegExps in a case statement and thus I can't assign the return of `/pattern/.named_captures`.

Here is what I would like to be able to do (for example):

```
while command != "quit"
  print "Command: "
  command = gets.chomp
  case command
  when /load (?<filename>\w+)/
    load(filename)
  end
end
```

Comment: I do not think this is possible in such a clever manner. However, the "magic capture variable" (`$n`) should still be available... I'm not sure why the -1 :(

Comment: Yeah I could use $1 but Ruby is great for its readability, I'm not looking to go back to Perl. Haha I'm not worried about losing made up points.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**named captures** set local variables when this syntax.

```
regex-literal =~ string
```

Dosen't set in other syntax. # See [rdoc(re.c)](http://goo.gl/NRZdk)

```
regex-variable =~ string

string =~ regex

regex.match(string)

case string
when regex
else
end
```

I like named captures too, but I don't like this behavior.
Now, we have to use $~ in case syntax.

```
case string
when /(?<name>.)/
  $~[:name]
else
end
```

Comment: $[~:name] didn't work for me, but $~[:name] did (per the other answer).

Comment: Sorry, thats my typo :<. Thank you for letting me know! @Lynn

Comment: FWIW, RuboCop recommends to use `$LAST_MATCH_INFO` instead of `$~`. [More info](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-cryptic-perlisms)

Answer (score 8):

This is ugly but works for me in Ruby 1.9.3:

```
while command != "quit"
  print "Command: "
  command = gets.chomp
  case command
  when /load (?<filename>\w+)/
    load($~[:filename])
  end
end
```

Alternatively you can use the English extension of `$~`, `$LAST_MATCH_INFO`.