# Named groups from regular expression in case statement

Tags: ruby, regex, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Named Captures with regex match in Ruby’s case…when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642009/using-named-captures-with-regex-match-in-rubys-case-when)

I'm trying to use named groups (capture groups with a name supplied) more often, to make my code more readable.

I'm trying to work out how to do that for a `case` statement:

```
date_field = "Wk 9"
date = case date_field
when /^Wk (?<weeks>\d+)$/ then 7 * Integer(weeks)
else raise "Unexpected date_field #{date_field.inspect}"
end
```

gives me

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `weeks' for main:Object
```

unlike

```
date_field = "Wk 9"
/^Wk (?<weeks>\d+)$/ =~ date_field
date = 7 * Integer(weeks)
date # => 63
```

Is there any way of doing a named group from a case statement?

Most similar question I could find: [How to write a Ruby switch statement (case...when) with regex and backreferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803647/how-to-write-a-ruby-switch-statement-case-when-with-regex-and-backreferences) , but the accepted answer only talks about using `$1` to `$9`.

Comment: What about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11006424/1004274

Comment: @oldergod nice StackOverflow-fu! (Duplicate tags [tag:switch-statement] and [tag:case-when] :()

Comment: Why removing the `case-when` tag if this is exactly what it is ? I could even ask why keeping the `switch-statement` tag since there is none in ruby.

Comment: @oldergod because `case-when` is used for SQL. Tags should have one and only one meaning. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambiguous-tags

Comment: You're right, I misread the tag definition, thank you!